# Writing to and reading from JSON an array of different types with Newtonsoft

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have an array of objects which I want to write to a json file and recover it later. The order of the objects must be preserved.

```
interface Task {}
class TaskA : Task {}
class TaskB : Task {}

var array = new Task[] {new TaskB(), new TaskA()};
```

If I use the simple `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(array);` I get a list of `Object`s as a result and no way of recovering type of the object (I can't recover type of the object by what fields it has).

I have found a way to write type of the object with it:

```
var serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer();
serializer.TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects;
```

I don't want to read every field manually and I believe there must be a way to tell Newtonsoft: read it as you would normally do, just take into account the type of the object. Is it trivial and I'm just missing something?

Comment: You could use `TypeNameHandling.Auto`: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm.

Comment: ... That link that I posted? It has an example of deserialization as well.

Comment: yes, sorry, I've missed the link somehow... It sounds exactly like a solution I'm looking for (why not post it as an answer btw?) but it still reads content of my array as "objects". Like, all `ChildrenTokens` have type `Object`. I don't understand why. I've tried `TypeNameHandling.Auto`, I've tried `TypeNameHandling.Object` - the type is written in JSON, but it's completely ignored during reading...

Comment: Oh, I've turned reading from `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` into `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Task[]>()` and it worked! I wish you'd post your suggestion as an answer so I could accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try wrapping your array or list in the `class`.
**Models definition part:**

```
public interface Task
{
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }
}

public class TaskA : Task
{
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }

    public double DoubleValue; // specific TaskA member
}

public class TaskB : Task
{
    public string StringProperty { get; set; }
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }

    public string StringValue; // specific TaskB member
}

public class MyModel
{
    public List<Task> tasks { get; set; }
}
```

**And usage:**

```cs
var data = new MyModel
{
    tasks = new List<Task>
    {
        new TaskA
        {
            IntProperty = 2,
            StringProperty = "A",
            DoubleValue = 11.1
        },
        new TaskB
        {
            IntProperty = 1,
            StringProperty = "B",
            StringValue = "Something else from B"
        }
    }
};

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects
};

var serializeData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, Formatting.Indented, settings);

var deserializedData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyModel>(serializeData,
    new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto
    });

Console.WriteLine($"Count of items: {deserializedData?.tasks?.Count}");

deserializedData?.tasks?.ForEach(item =>
{
    Console.WriteLine($"String Property: {item.StringProperty}," +
                      $"Int Property: {item.IntProperty}");

    switch (item)
    {
        case TaskA taskA:
            Console.WriteLine($"taskA inner member: {taskA.DoubleValue}");
            break;
        case TaskB taskB:
            Console.WriteLine($"taskB inner member: {taskB.StringProperty}");
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: I'll try, but could you also explain how it's supposed to solve my problem?

Comment: also are getters and setters necessary?

Comment: sorry I missed that, I will provide full example soon.

Comment: @elena please check if above. For any question I'm here, please let me know ;)

Comment: turned out it's not necessary to wrap anything into class, it works fine with collections when one specifies the expected return type to deserializer (Task[] in my case) and  `TypeNameHandling`

Comment: @elena, absolutely, that's the way it should work as well. Sorry, we misunderstood each other. I just wanted to say that with wrapping to class it's a bit more tight and controllable, but based on your code logic it can be different for sure.